# slidetoggle почему не получается выпадающее меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sliding-menu

Всем привет.

В общем, пытаюсь сделать выпадающее меню при нажатии кнопки на маленьких экранах, ничего не работает, вроде все перепроверил.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".pirozhok").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
      });
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fuckmenue ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%
  }
  .fuckmenue ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
  .fuckmenue ul {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="fuckheader">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fucklogo">
          <img src="img/ETS.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fuckmenue">
          <button class="pirozhok"><img src = "img/if_th-menu-outline_216423.png"></button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Если что, то все `Js` файлы подключены в конце `body tag в html`

Answer (score 0):

У Вас нет закрытия `$(document).ready(function() {`

В конец jq кода, добавьте `});`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".pirozhok").click(function() {
        
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
      });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fuckmenue ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%
  }
  .fuckmenue ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
  .fuckmenue ul {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .pirozhok {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fucklogo">
          <img src="img/ETS.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fuckmenue">
          <button class="pirozhok"><img src = "img/if_th-menu-outline_216423.png"></button>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, и правда не было закрывающей скобки - проставил

Comment: Но все равно ничего не работает, может img tag в buttonе мешает ?

Comment: @Mike_Gore У Вас пример в моем ответе работает? (Если нажать выполнить код?)

Comment: да, работает, не могу понять, в чем тогда у меня ошибка